# Project build error.Non resolvalbe parent POM in pom.xml in java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc

I am getting below error in `pom.xml` in springboot java application. I changed `java version` ,`springboot version` but error remains same. what should I do?

[image]

below is my `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.13</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I saw some of the answers and played with `relativePath` but did not work what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

This is an common problem facing now a days. This error causes because your editor haven't installed the spring boot properly. This you have to install all the maven files properly. Just follow the below steps to solve the problem.

> 1. Right click your spring boot project (demo) and select the option maven.
>    2. From the maven option you will get list of options. There you select update project or select download source.

Then your editor will install all the maven files for your spring boot project. And your error will be resolved.
Or
If it does not work just uninstall your spring tool suite and reinstall properly.

Any clarification please don't hesitate to comment your issue.. I am waiting for your comment..    Thank you